# 13027: point not in range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb

why do i get the error `13027: point not in range` when i run `db:create_indexes`?

the index declaration in the model is `index [[ :location, Mongo::GEO2D ]], :min => 200, :max => 200`

Answer (score 1):

This basically means one of the points in your collection is outside of the min/max that you specified. For example:

repl0:PRIMARY> db.points.insert({loc: {lat: 125, lon: 236}})

repl0:PRIMARY> db.points.ensureIndex({loc: '2d'}, {min: 126, max: 237})

point not in range

repl0:PRIMARY> db.points.ensureIndex({loc: '2d'}, {min: 125, max: 237})

in > 0

repl0:PRIMARY> db.points.ensureIndex({loc: '2d'}, {min: 124, max: 237})

In your example you also have min and max set to the same value.

Comment: That point is outside of the range you specified (200, 200). See the docs here for a better explanation:

Comment: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing#GeospatialIndexing-CreatingtheIndex